# Searchview crashes app

Tags: android, searchview

I'm using a searchview not as an menuItem but just in a layout. My minimum API level I support is 9 and the searchview is 11.

Now I created my searchview like this:

```
 <SearchView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"/>
```

in a lineairlayout. I noticed the warning so I changed it to:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/searchView"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"/>
```

But then my app crashes on new android firmware.

I use it like this in my app:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(this);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {

                FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
                if (s.length() == 0) {
                    transaction.show(mapFragment);
                } else {

                    transaction.hide(mapFragment);
                }

                updateListViewWithFilter(s);

                transaction.commit();

                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

I always gets this error:

```
06-10 07:15:35.420    1534-1534/be.test.android.dvl E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{be.test.android.dvl/be.test.android.amoffices.OfficesActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class SearchView
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class SearchView
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:128)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
            at be.test.android.base.BaseActivity.setContentView(BaseActivity.java:106)
            at be.test.android.amoffices.OfficesActivity.onCreate(OfficesActivity.java:59)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.SearchView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/be.test.android.dvl-1.apk]
            at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:128)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
            at be.test.android.base.BaseActivity.setContentView(BaseActivity.java:106)
            at be.test.android.amoffices.OfficesActivity.onCreate(OfficesActivity.java:59)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It says it doesn't find `android.view.SearchView` but I see you are using `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`. Perhaps an import issues? Or something to that direction?

Comment: I found the problem. Thanks. My editor didn't changed the import statements. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't change the import statements and the way I ussed the support widget.

This code is the only thing I changed besides the searchview.

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {

            android.support.v7.widget.SearchView  searchView = (android.support.v7.widget.SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
            searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(this);
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {

                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {

                    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
                    if (s.length() == 0) {
                        transaction.show(mapFragment);
                    } else {

                        transaction.hide(mapFragment);
                    }

                    updateListViewWithFilter(s);

                    transaction.commit();

                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
```

You can see I now casted the searchView to a support.searchview.

Comment: Did you app crash in the release version but worked ok on the debug version?

Comment: No,it did not in any of the 2 cases.

Comment: Are you using ProGuard?

Comment: Jup, my project uses ProGuard.

Comment: My app is crashing in the release version. I don't use proguard in the debug apk's. I thought I had a similar issue with what you describe here, but I guess not. At the moment the best lead I have is that it's something missing in the ProGuard configuration related to support librabry